# Spring password encoder for the default Django password format (pbkdf2_sha256)

Tags: django, spring, kotlin, spring-security, password-protection

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Security connected to a database originally generated by Django, in which all of the user passwords are stored in Django's `pbkdf2_sha256` [format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/).

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

Looking at Spring Security's `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder`, I was able to mostly figure it out and create an encoder that is able to encode and match Django's format.

After successfully unit testing it, I tried it on a sample value generated by Django... and it failed.

Why is this encoder not matching Django-generated values? Is Django performing some ~magic~ under the hood? I have also tried multiple replacements for Java's `SecurityFactory` implementation. This [line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ee693bd6cf4074f04ec51c6f3cfe87cad392f12/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L276) in Django's source code caught my attention as well, but writing the equivalent Kotlin did not fix the issue.

```kotlin
class DjangoPbkdf2PasswordEncoder : PasswordEncoder {

    companion object {
        private const val PREFIX = "pbkdf2_sha256"
        private const val SEPARATOR = "\$"
        private const val ITERATIONS = 180000
        private const val HASH_WIDTH = 256
        private const val ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"
    }

    private val saltGenerator: BytesKeyGenerator = KeyGenerators.secureRandom()

    private fun base64Decode(string: String): ByteArray {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(string)
    }

    private fun base64Encode(bytes: ByteArray): String {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
    }

    override fun encode(rawPassword: CharSequence): String {
        val salt = saltGenerator.generateKey()
        val hash = encodeWithSalt(rawPassword, salt)

        val encodedHash = base64Encode(hash)
        val encodedSalt = base64Encode(salt)

        return listOf(PREFIX, ITERATIONS, encodedSalt, encodedHash).joinToString(SEPARATOR)
    }

    private fun encodeWithSalt(rawPassword: CharSequence, salt: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        return encodeWithSaltAndIterations(rawPassword, salt, ITERATIONS)
    }

    private fun encodeWithSaltAndIterations(rawPassword: CharSequence, salt: ByteArray, iterations: Int): ByteArray {
        val keySpec = PBEKeySpec(
            rawPassword.toString().toCharArray(),
            salt,
            iterations,
            HASH_WIDTH
        )

        return try {
            SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)
                .generateSecret(keySpec)
                .encoded
        } catch (e: GeneralSecurityException) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Could not create hash", e)
        }
    }

    override fun matches(rawPassword: CharSequence, partsEncodedPassword: String): Boolean {
        if (!partsEncodedPassword.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Encoded password does not start with: $PREFIX")
        }

        val parts = partsEncodedPassword.split(SEPARATOR)
        if (parts.size != 4) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("The encoded password format does not have 4 parts")
        }

        val iterations = parts[1].toInt()
        val salt = base64Decode(parts[2])
        val hash = base64Decode(parts[3])

        return MessageDigest.isEqual(
            hash,
            encodeWithSaltAndIterations(rawPassword, salt, iterations)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the culprit on further inspection of the Django source code. It was using [this function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a89e975caf69ffdbec527f9fe84824e73a7c9cac/django/utils/crypto.py#L50) to generate an ASCII string to use as the salt. This means using Base64 encoding for the salt, as I did in my approach, is incorrect. To fix this:

```kotlin
// In encode()
val salt = saltGenerator.generateKey()
// ...
val encodedSalt = base64Encode(salt)
```

and

```kotlin
// In matches()
val salt = base64Decode(parts[2])
```

should be replaced with

```kotlin
val salt = generateSaltString()
val hash = encodeWithSalt(rawPassword, salt.toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))
```

and

```kotlin
val salt = parts[2].toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII)
```